# delayed 45 minutes or delayed by 45 minutes

Tags: expressions, word-usage

I have found this sentence in an English book : "Your plane is delayed 45 minutes"
I would spontanously have said " your plane is delayed by 45 minutes" I 'd like to know if both sentences are correct. Thanks in advance

Comment: Some words are "assumed" or "understood" to be there even when omitted.

Comment: I would say it should be future. Your plane _will_ be delayed _for_ forty five minutes. Or 'your plane _has been delayed_ . . . _by_ forty five minutes. The present tense seems odd, to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, they are both correct. In American usage, it is more appropriate and common to use the shorter version, "delayed 45 minutes." The addition of the word "by" is superfluous and could be perceived by some as affected.

Comment: No, *by* is **not** superfluous, it's elided in the shorter form in fact. Grammar requires it, AmE may condone its absence.